# How to increase time between typing and search event fire in ExtJs Grid Filter

Tags: extjs

I have a extjs grid. in that i have added plugin

```
    plugins = {
        ptype: 'gridfilters'
    };
```

Here what happens is when i type in filter, it immediately starts searching before i complete my word. How can we increase this time for grid filter?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  I have been given the task of adding a feature to an old app using ExtJS grid and this issue is a problem. Is there a way to increase the time?

Answer (score 0):

You can use ExtJs defer Function:

```
Ext.Function.defer(function(){
        == Your Code ==
    }, 1000);
```

Comment: Actually there is no function, i am just using grids inbuilt plugin, which will fire search event once i type.

Comment: Which Extjs version are you using? In Extjs 6 there is no "gridfilters"

Comment: I am using extjs 5, but its also there in extjs 6. you can find "Ext.grid.filters.Filters" in ext-all.js